# Why doesn't progress spinner work after closing alert dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

My progress bar is just a spinner.

I am showing two options to user and when user clicks an option, I show a dialog, so that user reads and understands it.

This is what I want. 
When they click positive, it should show the spinner and keep calling service on background. 
When they click negative, it should make the option unchecked.

Here is the code.

This radioGroup.setOnClickListener goes into onCreateView method of a fragment.

```
    public class Choose_CountryFragment extends Fragment {
        private RadioGroup radioGroup;
        private TextView textView;
        private String countryChosen = null;
        ConnectionStatus connectionStatus = new ConnectionStatus(getContext());
        public Choose_CountryFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose__country, container, false);

          radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.country_choice_radio);
         radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        switch(checkedId){
                            case R.id.countryCanada:
                                // do operations specific to this selection
                                countryChosen = "Canada";
                                Intent explicitServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class);
                                explicitServiceIntent.putExtra("country", "Canada");
                                getActivity().startService(explicitServiceIntent);
                                connectionStatus.showProgress();
                                break;
                            case R.id.countryUSA:
                                countryChosen = "USA";
                                Dialog dialog = onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
                                dialog.show();
                                connectionStatus.showProgress();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click Got it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            builder.setMessage(R.string.SignUpWarningInfo)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.gotIt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent explicitServiceIntentUSA = new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class);
                            explicitServiceIntentUSA.putExtra("country", countryChosen );
                            getActivity().startService(explicitServiceIntentUSA);

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                        
                            return;
                        }
                    });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            return builder.create();
        }
    }
}
```

ConnectionStatus.java

```
public class ConnectionStatus {

    private Context _context;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    public ConnectionStatus(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }
    public void showProgress(){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
}
```

Error happens when I click USA. 
Error I get

```
         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:154)
                  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:109)
                  at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
                  at com.a2.a2.ConnectionStatus.showProgress(ConnectionStatus.java:66)
                  at com.a2.a2.signUp.Choose_CountryFragment$1.onCheckedChanged(Choose_CountryFragment.java:73)
```

Comment: post full `Choose_CountryFragment` code

Comment: @kishorejethava Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Context` returning `null`

Change code in **Choose_CountryFragment**

```
public class Choose_CountryFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
   protected Context mContext;
   private ConnectionStatus connectionStatus
   ...

    public Choose_CountryFragment() {
    }

      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose__country, container, false);
       ...
       connectionStatus = new ConnectionStatus(mContext);// initialize ConnectionStatus here
       ...
    }

}
```

Override **onAttach** Inside `Choose_CountryFragment`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I am trying to understand here. 

When you say, "Your `Context`returning `null`" 
ConnectionStatus connectionStatus = new ConnectionStatus(getContext());  //You mean to say getContext() is returning null

Comment: Who passed context to onAttach() ? I am a newbie. Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: Ok. How is onAttach() called inside Choose_Country_Fragment?

Comment: because `Choose_CountryFragment extends Fragment`. explore `Fragment` for knowledge

Answer (score 0):

In `Fragment`, you have to use:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity);
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), the `getActivity()` method returns the `Activity` this `Fragment` is currently associated with it.

**Edit**:
In `Activity` class, you have to use like:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityClassName.this);
```

Comment: Where are you including this method in `Fragment` or `Activity` class ?

Comment: in Fragment.Why not the current work? Could you explain that?

Comment: You are using like: `Context mContext` or something ?

Comment: `getActivity()` method on Fragment, to get the activity it is attached to and `context` is needed in an instance method of an activity, you can use `this`.

Comment: First of all, Why should I use `ProgressDialog` and not `Dialog`

Comment: `Dialog` is general class which is extends by `ProgressDialog` and `AlertDialog`. In short `ProgressDialog` is `Dialog` with `ProgressBar`

Comment: Yeah, `Dialog` is base class of `Progress Dialog`, `Alert Dialog`. There are also `DatePicker/TimePicker Dialog`.